# How should HTTP server behave when failed to parse request data?

Tags: http

A client may send invalid data which cannot be parsed properly to HTTP server.

For instance, a bad client could send `GED /a/b/c HTTP/1.1\r\n` where GED is not a proper HTTP method name.
Or, a client may miss `\r` for new line.

Is there a status code to denote wrong raw data from client?
Or is there any guideline about HTTP server for such situation?

Comment: [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)?

Comment: _"Or is there any guideline about HTTP server for such situation?"_ - there are the RFCs that describe the HTTP protocol, have you tried reading those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GED /a/b/c HTTP/1.1\r\n where GED is not a proper HTTP method name.

Usually this is `501 Not Implemented`

> Or, a client may miss \r for new line.

Usually this is `400 Bad Request`

> Or is there any guideline about HTTP server for such situation?

If it helps, [I wrote a guideline](https://evertpot.com/http/) on all HTTP status codes and when to use them.